# Is there a limit to how many people you can block on Steam?

Tags: steam

Steam limits the number of friends you can have, but I am uncertain if there is a limit on how many people you can block.

I tried to google it, but information I found was conflicting. Some said it was infinite, others said it was 500, again others said it depended on the Steam Level. However, none of those were from official sources and merely sounded like best guesses.

So is there a limit on how many people you can block on Steam?

Comment: I am not entirely certain but I believe Steam running on a 64-bit system would allow for 9,223,372,036,854,775,807 blocked users.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An official response from Steam Support:

[image: Steam Response]

Comment: To support Lemon's answer, they answered me too today. Here is a screenshot saying "There is no limit to the number of users you can have blocked at the same time." https://imgur.com/a/tLlTR

Answer (score -1):

There is no limit to how many you can block. I have blocked over 500 people.

Comment: Dude, chill with those run-ons.

Comment: "or how many friends you can get" I think that one is limited by your Steam level. I forget what the base level is, but you get 5 more for ever level. Unless you are talking about (unanswered) friend requests.

Comment: Same question as the last person who said it's infinite: How do you know? Is there any reliable source for this claim?